# How to remove a category from the archives output?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to remove posts of a category from the archives page. I'm not sure how to do that. The code I'm using for it is from the Zen Habits blog.

The code can be found here: http://zenhabits.net/install/

I've also put the archives code here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ff924f5ffe3b496ce500185f0aebf00e47051b4

And I have code that removes posts from the same category from the main-page, which is in my `functions.php` file if it's any help (as it does a similar thing to what I'm trying to achieve):

```
function excludeCat($query) {
if ( $query->is_home ) {
$query->set('cat', '-26');
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat');
```

Answer (score 0):

Tester :D

```
function excludeCat($query) {
  if ( $query->is_home ) {
    $query->set('category__not_in', array( -26 ));
  }
  return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat');
```

Comment: I tried adding that to `functions.php` and I got error messages when I reloaded the mock site. The only page I'm trying to remove it from is the archives page (page ID is 148) so would that be specified with a `is_page()`?
Here's two links I've found that may help (I didn't have any initial success applying it to my code):
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/category_not_in-parameter
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/